# Align multiple div elements above each other while keeping responsiveness

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make the following `div` elements more responsive: 
http://jsfiddle.net/7q5eevpt/

Right now, when viewing on a small screen the trapezoid overlaps the image. 
How can I get it so that the trapezoid *pops* under the picture and sits there? This is what I'd like it to look like: [image]

Basically, I want the trapezoid to be centered under the orange bar.

This is my CSS

```
#home-feature5 {
    height:618px;
    width:1210px;
    position:relative;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.photo {
    bottom: 37px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 20px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.photo img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.bg {
    background-color:#f88b5c;
    width:100%;
    height:95px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
}

  .trap5 { 
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    bottom:5%;
    z-index:4; 
    right:5%;
}
.trap5:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 0px 5px #1c628f;

    top: -4%; bottom: -11%; left: -3%; right: -3%;
    z-index: ;

    -webkit-transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-30deg);
    transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-30deg);
}
  .trap5header {
    font-family:"AmericanTypewriterStd", sans-serif; 
    color:#1c628f; 
    font-size:18pt; 
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:600;

  }

  .trap5text {
    font-family:"Scout", sans-serif; 
    font-size:10pt; 
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.trap5 { 
        position:relative;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, get rid of all your absolute positioned elements. And I mean ALL. And if you want it to be responsive, then think in terms of percentages, not fixed sizes.

So your CSS would be as simple as this:

```
#home-feature5 {
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    position:relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.photo {
    top: 0px;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
.photo img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.bg {
    background-color:#f88b5c;
    width:100%;
    height:95px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    position:relative;
}
.trap5 {
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    top:5%;
    z-index:4;
    margin:10px auto 30px;
}
.trap5:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 0px 5px #1c628f;
    top: -4%;
    bottom: -11%;
    left: -3%;
    right: -3%;
    z-index:;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-30deg);
    transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-30deg);
}
.trap5header {
    font-family:"AmericanTypewriterStd", sans-serif;
    color:#1c628f;
    font-size:18pt;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:600;
}
.trap5text {
    font-family:"Scout", sans-serif;
    font-size:10pt;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .trap5 {
        position:relative;
    }
}
```

[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bag9vypy/)

**EDIT:** just a small fix for FULL responsive behavior.

.trap5 {
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    max-width: 450px;
    max-height: 200px;
    position:relative;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    top:5%;
    z-index:4;
    margin:10px auto 30px;
}

```
of course width:50% could be changed to anything, it's just an example, the important part is it won't be wider than 450px width
```

Comment: you're welcome :) just a comment: I mentioned not to use fixed sizes and... I left some fixed sizes (my bad). See edit on what can you do there